# Commerce subterms

Tags: commerce, taxonomy-terms

I have a commerce site  with category and subterns.
Example my taxonomy hierarchy:
paper-book (category1)
travel guide (subCategory1)
children's book (subCategory2)
cookbook (subCategory3)
e-book
history (subCategory1)
romance(subCategory2)

What I want is:
1. create a page that contains only main categories: paper-book and e-book (page1) with links to
2. another page that has the followings content: a list of all main category products, a list of all main category subcategories, a facet blocks.

Example:
1. Page1 has two image fields: paper-book and e-book;
2. If user clicks on 'paper-book' I have to open another page that contains: all paper-books; a menu with travel, children's book, cookbook links; facet blocks(e.g. publisher year, publisher name).

How can I do this?
Using views with contextual filter (has taxnomy terms) ecc I created a page with all main taxonomy term with links to another page that list main category product, but I can't add facets.

Thanks in advice

Comment: have you tried making pages in views? which drupal version are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using commerce_kickstart 7.x-2.38.

Comment: install 'views' module and create a new view. It's very simple.

Comment: I'm using view but I can't view all products. Example: if I create a product1 with tags: paper-book and travel guide tags, I can't see product1. If I create a product2 with only paper-book I can see it.